# Laravel 9 get current locale form i18Next in controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, locale, i18next

I'm trying to get the current user locale in `controller`
Found many references that answers this but for `react` or `vue` that didn't work in my case

I tried

```
Lang::locale();

Config::get('app.locale');

app()->getLocale()
```

Nothing worked, though when I change language I see in `console`

```
i18next: languageChanged de
```

triggered by:

```
// Re-init translation service
     i18next.on('languageChanged', function() {
        selector.forEach(function(item) {
              item.innerHTML = i18next.t(item.getAttribute("data-i18n"));
        });
   });
```

How to get this value in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in another way without using `i18Next`

Create a new `column` in database table and call it `user_locale`

On language dropdown items `href` tag add route on each item as your needs:

```
href="{{ route('users.setUserLocale') }}/en"
```

Define new route

```
Route::get('users/{user_locale?}','UsersController@setUserLocale')->name('users.setUserLocale');
```

Add in controller

```
use DB;
use Auth;

    public function setUserLocale($user_locale = NULL) {
            $thisUser = Auth::user();
            $dbQry = DB::table('users')->where('id', $thisUser->id)->update(
                [
                    'user_locale' => $user_locale,
                ]
            );
            return back();
        }
```

This way each time a user changes the language the value will be updated in `user_locale` column with the current language code

To get the `locale`, you can simply do

```
thisUser = Auth::user();
$locale = $thisUser->user_locale;
```